# mod_rewrite for friendly URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to implement Permalinks into my content management system and I seem to be stuck at a problem with mod_rewrite. I have a PHP file (`single.php`) which will display a single post based on the Permalink name that gets passed through to it. i.e. `post.php?permalink=name-of-post-here`.

Here are the rules I've set up:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([a-z]+)?$ $1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([a-z]+)?$ post.php?permalink=$1
```

Also, how do I get the `date/year` (i.e. 2012), and assign that as a parameter for the PHP file. (i.e. `post.php?year=2012?permalink=name-of-post-here`) & can all of this be done using mod_rewrite?

Many Thanks.

Want to change

`http://www.website.com/post.php?year=2012&permalink=post-name-here`

to

`http://www.website.com/2012/post-name-here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/(.*)$ post.php?year=$1&permalink=$2 [L,R,NC,QSA]
```

If you don't want external redirect (change URL in browser) then remove `R` flag.

Comment: Many thanks, this was exactly the answer I was looking for :)